# Is using member variables as bad as using globals?

Tags: class-design, globals

Is this an acceptable use of member variables:

One method sets the variables so that another method can use them.  Would it be better to return the value in a list or tuple from `func1`? If I don't do that, is this as bad as a global variable?

```
class test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    private void func1(){
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
    }

    private void func2(){
        int d = a + b + c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the purpose of a class is to *encapsulate* code and data.  So yes, this is an acceptable use.

Comment: Your original use of the word "class variable" was wrong, and the formatting of the code was horrible. I took the freedom to fix this.

Comment: Worth to note: Globals aren't bad because they are inherently bad. Globals are "bad" because they often allow you to lean on bad design and bad habits while developing. On some situations, they are pretty fine and sometimes even the optimal way of doing this or that thing. However, most often than not, they allow one to be lazier and more careless, leading to unworkable spaghetti code. That's why people claim they are "bad".

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of a member function, member variables look somewhat like globals, that is a correct observation. They "live" in an outer scope and have a longer lifetime than the local variables inside the function.

However, this is **intentional** - the idea of a class is to allow this kind of access to a small, restricted area of the program (the member functions of the class), but not to the whole program.

So - as one extreme - if your whole, large program (and by large, I mean larger than approx. 1K to 5K lines of code) consists of just one class, member variables *are* becoming effectively globals. This is still true when single classes become "too large" and overuse member variables for tossing a lot of data around between different functions in arbitrary ways.

The better alternative is not to avoid member variables at all. The alternative is to design programs using lots of small, cohesive classes, where member variables are used *deliberately*. But don't expect to get a full receipt in this answer for doing this right - there have been a lot of books written about "good" class design, and there are different schools of thought and paradigms for OO programming. So when you continue practicing, you will surely learn in a few months when to introduce a member variable and when not, and how to use them properly.

Answer (score 2):

These are instance variables, and a different set of these instance variables are associated with each instance of the type.  These are much more restricted than global variables, so that's the good news.

The bad news is that in this example, a field is being computed only by calling `func2()`, and other fields are only initialized by calling `func1 ()` .  (We are assuming that `d` is another instance variable, though not actually shown in the post.)

What this means is that we have a vague protocol, if you will, where there are steps not necessarily ordered (and though ordering may be desired, there's no way for the compiler to verify the intended ordering):

1. construction — no field is "properly" initialized, they are all defaulted (or uninitialized) depending on the language.
2. calling `func1()` — now `a`, `b`, and `c` have values, but `d` doesn't
3. calling `func2()` — now `d` does, too.

But `func2()` could be called before `func1()`, so `d` might have an unclear value, and, `func1()` and `func2()` can continually be invoked, possibly changing things to make them even more unclear, as in: construction, then `func2()`, then `func1()`, then `func2()` again..  Imagine the different values that `d` (and the others) take on at various points.

There are better approaches.  For one example, using immutable objects and several different types we can avoid the intermediate undefined values of the instance fields, and, get the compiler's type system to help identify errors in ordering.

Another way to look at this is that

1. All fields of an instance should be initialized when the object is created.
2. If you have fields used to pass data between two methods, you probably have a use case for separate objects.

All the fields of an object should have the same lifetime.  If some fields have a shorter lifetime than others (lifetime = valid time from after initialization to no longer in use), then you have an indication of separate classes/objects.

We should not use instance fields to pass parameters from one method to another b/c by definition, parameters have a shorter lifetime than the object itself.  Find another way to pass the parameters or create a separate object for that purpose.

Of course, there are situations where the most practical answer is to violate these principles..  But on principle, fields should be grouped together as a binding of items into an abstraction, so items that don't bind for the same lifetime should be a separate object/abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erik and Doc, here's a different view to the same problem.

Member variables should represent object state. If they are just temporary storage for some operation it is bad because it unnecessarily blows up scope and it pollutes the class with meaningless noise. Do not be tempted to do this because "now I only need to declare them once so it is shorter".

Answer (score 0):

Your example is kind of theoretical and abstract; there are no indications of what `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` really represent, nor the overall class. Since we don't really know anything about the relationship between the different pieces here, it's hard to give any definitive answer to your question.

A couple of thoughts though: If the variables are natural and necessary (required) parts of the class, then they may well be defined the way you do. You might want to give them value when the object is created - typically in constructor:

```
class test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    // Using a constructor for the class instead of a private method
    public test(){
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
    }

    private void func2(){
        int d = a + b + c;
    }
}
```

If that does not suit you, you might define a separate class to contain the data, and return that from your `func1()`. That will make it easier to call it directly from `func2()`. Something like this might help keep things separated and more manageable as your codebase grows:

```
class testData
{
    // could also use a constructor here if you 
    // prefer, and not allow the values to change later:

    // public testData(int valA, int valB, int valC){
    //   a = valA;
    //   b = valB;
    //   c = valC;
    // }

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

class test
{

    private testData func1(){
        testData set = new testData(); 
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;

        // Alternative, using constructor:
        // testData set = new testData(1, 2, 3); 
   }

    private void func2(){
        // Note that calling func1() here ensures 
        // required values are fetched before the calculation. 
        testData = func1();
        int d = testData.a + testData.b + testData.c;
    }
}
```

There are probably countless other ways of doing this, depending on what data you're working with, and the relations involved. I'd say the main things to keep in mind are:

- Ensure that any required data will be available when needed (the examples above ensure `func2()`won't try to calculate anything before `a`, `b` and `c` have been given values).
- Limit scope and accessibility as much as possible, so long as it does not complicate usage too much, but don't fret too much about this unless the variables are publicly exposed, and/or the class has grown to a size where it's getting harder to keep track of things.
- Think about what data actually *belongs* together. Try to "group" data together based on such relationships and according to natural areas of responsibility rather than based on what is the most quick and simple solution here and now.